# How to club a week and day string like "21Fr" into DateTime format?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parsing, datetime, date-parsing

Hi I am having the day and week of the year that is in the format "21Fr" (21st week of year and day as Friday) and time in "06:00". I want to club this 2 values and get the output in below format? Any help would be highly appreciable

> 23/05/2014 06:00:00

Comment: Your 21st week can be change depends on `FirstDayOfWeek`. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @SonerGönül yes i will update my qtn with the code

Comment: I suggest _clubbing_ whoever gave you datetime in this format into giving you a better format.

Comment: @SonerGönül not only that, but how first week of the year is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *strongly* recommend changing your input format if possible. However, here's one approach:

```
// parse the input
string input = "21Fr";
// assuming week number is always 2 characters. e.g.: 01, 02, ..., 21, ...
int weeks = int.Parse(input.Substring(0, 2));
// assuming abbreviated day names like this
string[] abbrDayNames = { "Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We","Th", "Fr", "Sa" };
int dayOfWeekValue = Array.IndexOf(abbrDayNames, input.Substring(2));
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = (DayOfWeek)dayOfWeekValue;

// now let's build the DateTime
// start from first day of year, 6:00 AM
DateTime parsed = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1 ,1, 6, 0, 0);
// add first part, weeks
parsed = parsed.AddDays((weeks - 1) * 7);
// reset to first day of week
parsed = parsed.AddDays(-(int)parsed.DayOfWeek);
// then add the second part, day of week
parsed = parsed.AddDays((int)dayOfWeek);
```

This also assumes (based on your sample output) week 21 means you're *in* the 21st week of year.

Comment: thank u  so much it worked. the data is returned from mainframe database cant help to change.